# SQL code is removing duplicate values in error

Tags: sql

My SQL code is removing duplicate values of "Time" specific to Project Description.  For example, if a time value for a specific project is included two or more times, the data is only pulling the value once skewing the results.

I've tried adding `SUM(PMTT_DailyTime.Time)` as 'Sum of Time" and this creates a different problem and inaccurate results. It multiplies the sum values by the number of an irrelevant field.

```
SELECT View_ProjectsInfoDecoded.ProjectNbr
    , View_ProjectsInfoDecoded.Department
    , View_ProjectsInfoDecoded.ProjectDesc
    , View_ProjectsInfoDecoded.ProjectStartDate
    , View_ProjectsInfoDecoded.ProjectCompletionDate
    , View_ProjectsInfoDecoded.VoidInd
    , View_ProjectsInfoDecoded.ProjectStatus
    , View_ProjectsInfoDecoded.ProjectType
    , DatePart("yyyy", PMTT_DailyTime.ReportDate) AS [ReportYear]
    , PMTT_DailyTime.Time
    , PMTT_DailyTime.VoidInd
    , View_ProjectsBuilderInfoDecoded.ProjectHealth
    , View_ProjectsBuilderInfoDecoded.PrimaryBuilder
    , View_ProjectsBuilderInfoDecoded.CurrentProjectStatus
FROM View_ProjectsInfoDecoded 
    LEFT JOIN View_ProjectsBuilderInfoDecoded ON View_ProjectsInfoDecoded.Department = View_ProjectsBuilderInfoDecoded.Department AND View_ProjectsInfoDecoded.ProjectNbr = View_ProjectsBuilderInfoDecoded.ProjectNbr 
    LEFT JOIN PMTT_DailyTime ON (View_ProjectsBuilderInfoDecoded.Department = PMTT_DailyTime.Department) AND  (View_ProjectsBuilderInfoDecoded.ProjectNbr= PMTT_DailyTime.ProjectNbr) 
WHERE (View_ProjectsInfoDecoded.Department IN ('107')) 
    And (View_ProjectsInfoDecoded.ProjectStatus <>'Cancel') 
    And (dbo.View_ProjectsInfoDecoded.VoidInd = 'N' OR dbo.View_ProjectsInfoDecoded.VoidInd IS NULL) 
    AND (PMTT_DailyTime.VoidInd = 'N' OR PMTT_DailyTime.VoidInd IS NULL) 
    AND ((DATEDIFF(MONTH, View_ProjectsInfoDecoded.ProjectCompletionDate,GETDATE()) <= 12) OR (View_ProjectsInfoDecoded.ProjectCompletionDate IS NULL) OR (View_ProjectsInfoDecoded.ProjectCompletionDate='' )) 
GROUP BY View_ProjectsInfoDecoded.Department, View_ProjectsInfoDecoded.ProjectNbr
, View_ProjectsInfoDecoded.ProjectDesc, View_ProjectsInfoDecoded.ProjectStatus
, View_ProjectsInfoDecoded.EstStartDate, View_ProjectsInfoDecoded.ProjectStartDate
, View_ProjectsInfoDecoded.ProjectCompletionDate, View_ProjectsInfoDecoded.Complexity
, View_ProjectsInfoDecoded.ProjectType, View_ProjectsInfoDecoded.VoidInd
, View_ProjectsBuilderInfoDecoded.ProjectHealth, View_ProjectsBuilderInfoDecoded.PrimaryBuilder
, View_ProjectsBuilderInfoDecoded.CurrentProjectStatus, PMTT_DailyTime.VoidInd
, DatePart("yyyy", PMTT_DailyTime.ReportDate), PMTT_DailyTime.Time
```

I think this is an easy fix in the Group function or the type of joins used.  But not sure...

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the tables' structure as `CREATE` statements, sample data as `INSERT INTO` statements, the desired result for that sample data and the tag corresponding to the DBMS and its version you use.

Comment: Do you want to group by the time or aggregate it? Sample data with expected results would help, it's difficult to know what you need just based on a query that isn't working.

Comment: A little formatting goes a long way..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a re-factoring of your query to use aliases, include line breaks and re-order columns, you will notice you have two additional `GROUP BY` fields that are not included in `SELECT`: *EstStartDate* and *p.Complexity*. As a result, the `SELECT` columns may show repeated values over the distinct groupings of these omitted two fields.

For a more readable aggregate query, consider including the same columns in `GROUP BY` also in `SELECT` clause without omitting any. Do note: per SQL standard, you cannot have a column in `SELECT` that does not appear in `GROUP BY`. However, the reverse as your query does is valid. Alternatively, simply run the analogous `SELECT DISTINCT` without `GROUP BY`.

```
SELECT p.ProjectNbr, p.Department, p.ProjectDesc, p.ProjectStartDate, p.ProjectCompletionDate, 
       p.VoidInd, p.ProjectStatus, p.ProjectType, DatePart("yyyy", d.ReportDate) AS [ReportYear], 
       d.Time, d.VoidInd, b.ProjectHealth, b.PrimaryBuilder, b.CurrentProjectStatus

FROM (View_ProjectsInfoDecoded p
LEFT JOIN View_ProjectsBuilderInfoDecoded b
       ON (p.Department = b.Department) AND (p.ProjectNbr = b.ProjectNbr)) 
LEFT JOIN PMTT_DailyTime d 
       ON (b.Department = d.Department) AND (b.ProjectNbr = d.ProjectNbr) 

WHERE (p.Department IN ('107')) 
  AND (p.ProjectStatus <> 'Cancel') 
  AND (dbo.p.VoidInd = 'N' OR dbo.p.VoidInd IS NULL) 
  AND (d.VoidInd = 'N' OR d.VoidInd IS NULL) 
  AND ((DATEDIFF(MONTH, p.ProjectCompletionDate, GETDATE()) <= 12) 
       OR (p.ProjectCompletionDate IS NULL) 
       OR (p.ProjectCompletionDate='')
      ) 

GROUP BY p.ProjectNbr, p.Department, p.ProjectDesc, p.ProjectStartDate, p.ProjectCompletionDate, 
         p.VoidInd, p.ProjectStatus, p.ProjectType, DatePart("yyyy", d.ReportDate), 
         d.Time, d.VoidInd, b.ProjectHealth, b.PrimaryBuilder, b.CurrentProjectStatus, 

         p.EstStartDate, p.Complexity  -- ADDITIONAL NON-SELECT FIELDS
```

Comment: You are wonderful for helping me. I figured out to add a field that has completely unique values (a time stamp) to add to the Group By field so that the values returned for sum of time are now accurate.  Previously, none of my fields in the Group By statement were returning a completely unique result and SQL was removing values in the sum of time it thought was duplicate. I'm sure these strategies would work as well and will reference them in the future!!  Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `Group By` clause, but have no aggregate function in your `Select` statement. This results in the same behavior as using `Select Distinct`. Removing the `Group By` clause will include the duplicate records you seem to be looking for.

```
SELECT View_ProjectsInfoDecoded.ProjectNbr, View_ProjectsInfoDecoded.Department, View_ProjectsInfoDecoded.ProjectDesc, View_ProjectsInfoDecoded.ProjectStartDate, View_ProjectsInfoDecoded.ProjectCompletionDate, View_ProjectsInfoDecoded.VoidInd, View_ProjectsInfoDecoded.ProjectStatus, View_ProjectsInfoDecoded.ProjectType, DatePart("yyyy", PMTT_DailyTime.ReportDate) AS [ReportYear],  PMTT_DailyTime.Time, PMTT_DailyTime.VoidInd, View_ProjectsBuilderInfoDecoded.ProjectHealth, View_ProjectsBuilderInfoDecoded.PrimaryBuilder, View_ProjectsBuilderInfoDecoded.CurrentProjectStatus

FROM (View_ProjectsInfoDecoded LEFT JOIN View_ProjectsBuilderInfoDecoded ON (View_ProjectsInfoDecoded.Department = View_ProjectsBuilderInfoDecoded.Department) AND (View_ProjectsInfoDecoded.ProjectNbr = View_ProjectsBuilderInfoDecoded.ProjectNbr)) LEFT JOIN
PMTT_DailyTime ON (View_ProjectsBuilderInfoDecoded.Department = PMTT_DailyTime.Department) AND  (View_ProjectsBuilderInfoDecoded.ProjectNbr= PMTT_DailyTime.ProjectNbr) 

WHERE (View_ProjectsInfoDecoded.Department IN ('107')) And (View_ProjectsInfoDecoded.ProjectStatus <>'Cancel') And 
(dbo.View_ProjectsInfoDecoded.VoidInd = 'N' OR dbo.View_ProjectsInfoDecoded.VoidInd IS NULL) AND (PMTT_DailyTime.VoidInd = 'N' OR PMTT_DailyTime.VoidInd IS NULL) 
AND ((DATEDIFF(MONTH, View_ProjectsInfoDecoded.ProjectCompletionDate,GETDATE()) <= 12) OR (View_ProjectsInfoDecoded.ProjectCompletionDate IS NULL) OR (View_ProjectsInfoDecoded.ProjectCompletionDate='' ))
```

Comment: You are wonderful for helping me. I figured out to add a field that has completely unique values (a time stamp) to add to the Group By field so that the values returned for sum of time are now accurate.  Previously, none of my fields in the Group By statement were returning a completely unique result and SQL was removing values in the sum of time it thought was duplicate. I'm sure these strategies would work as well and will reference them in the future!!  Thanks!!